# how do I pipe to the "for" command?

Tags: windows, command-line

How do I pipe to the for command. So instead of

```
    C:\asd>ipconfig | findstr "Address" >a

   C:\asd>for /f "tokens=15" %f in (a) do @echo %f
   192.168.1.3
```

I would like to be able to do it on one line.

```
C:\asd>ipconfig | findstr "Address" | for /f "tokens=15" %f do @echo %f
do was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although it doesn't appear to be documented, you can pipe to the command inside the FOR command. I first learned about it from [this example](http://www.askapache.com/windows/advanced-batch-scripting.html#LISTSERVICES_lists_services_returns_CALLer):

```
SC query | FOR /F "tokens=2" %%i IN ('FIND /I "SERVICE_NAME"') DO @ECHO %%i
```

This modified version of your code works:

```
C:\>ipconfig | for /f "tokens=14" %f in ('findstr "Address"') do @echo %f
192.168.x.x
192.168.y.y
```

You can also use "more" inside the FOR command, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file/6980605#6980605), to parse input piped in from an arbitrary command:

```
C:\>ipconfig | findstr "Address" | for /f "tokens=14" %f in ('more') do @echo %f
192.168.x.x
192.168.y.y
```

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the documentation for `for` (run `for /?` to see it), I don't think `for /f` will read from a pipe.  The only valid sources are file-set, "string", and 'command'.

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
```

You could put the command inside the `for` like this:

```
for /f "tokens=15" %f in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "Address"') do @echo %f

192.168.x.x
192.168.y.y
```

(thanks to neurolysis for pointing out it has to be `^|` and not just `|`)

Or you could try putting `ipconfig | findstr "Address"` in a separate batch script and calling:

```
for /f "tokens=14" %f in ('ipaddresses') do @echo %f
```

(assuming you called the script `ipaddresses`).

Or you could use `for` to do the work of `findstr` too, like this:

```
for /f "tokens=2,14" %i in ('ipconfig') do @if %i==Address. @echo %j

192.168.x.x
192.168.y.y
```

it's not quite the same because it won't match IPv6 addresses, but something along those lines could work.

Also note that I changed `tokens=15` to `tokens=14`.  I think the last field on the line is token 14.  Works for me anyway.

Comment: If you look at my question, you'll see I know about using a temp file, that was my example, I just called the file 'a'.  With what you say at the start though, you have a point, the closest to doing the pipe.. is putting the command in the "in".    And I suppose that since one can do that, that might explain why one can't use a pipe to for. It looks like one can't use a pipe to it. Interestin also you mention the term pipeline.. I hadn't heard the pipe called that.. but a google shows it.

Comment: For the record, the reason it "doesn't seem to support pipelines" is simply because you haven't escaped it, it is piping `for` instead of `ipconfig`. Just do `for /f "tokens=15" %f in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "Address"') do @echo %f`, when `^` is the escape character.

Comment: Thanks neurolysis, will update my answer to include that.

Comment: Well I meant piping to For, like before it. But i'm convinced one can't.  But can in the "in" as in Mikel's suggestion. But trying Mikel's line, I did run into a problem with Mikel's line.. and you(neurolysis) fixed that by escaping the pipe.

Comment: @barlop, yes, I will remove the tempfile suggestion.  "pipeline" is a UNIX term meaning a series of commands with pipes in the middle.

Comment: @Mikel good use of batch programming there with the IF.. Do you have any suggestions on NT batch file programming eg where you might've picked up ideas about using "if"?

Comment: @barlop, I just open up a command prompt, type `help | more`, and choose a command that sounds related (e.g. `if`) then run `if /?` or `help if`.

Comment: very good answer though check out the new answer!